# Prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $\frac{f(n)}{10^n}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

For each $f \in {0,1}^\mathbb{N}$,it is $\phi(f)$=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $\frac{f(n)}{10^n}$ is convergent.

If $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}|=L$ and $L<1$ , so it's proven.

$a_n=\frac{f(n)}{10^n}$ and $a_n+1=\frac{f(n+1)}{10^n+1}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{\frac{f(n+1)}{10^n+1}}{\frac{f(n)}{10^n}}|$ =

$\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{f(n+1)}{10(f(n))}|$

Ican't develop further because I can't get a direct relationship between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$

Any tips?

Comment: You could use the comparison test.

Comment: Why not use the monotone convergence theorem? The partial sums are monotone and bounded above by $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^n} = \frac{10}{9}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio test isn't appropriate here since $f(n) = 0$ is possible for some $n$.  On the other hand, since $$\sqrt[n]{\frac{|f(n)|}{10^n}} \le \frac 1{10}$$ you could use the root test, or even more simply the comparison test with the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{10^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|f(n)|\le 1$ for all $n$, the partial sums satisfy
$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{f(n)}{10^n}\right|\le\sum_{n=0}^N\left|\frac{f(n)}{10^n}\right|\le\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{1}{10^n}=\frac{1-10^{N+1}}{1-10}.$$
Try taking it from here.